# Ruby on rails: printing the variable name for debugging purposes in the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

Lets say I have i variable var witch is a pointer to another variable named user_id.

How do I puts var such that I can see in the console user_id = (whatever the value is)

Reason why I want to do this, is because I want to write a method called print_debug_block, where you give it an array of variables, and it prints in the following format:

```
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||  
var1 = valOfVar1  
var2 = valOfVar2  
var3 = valOfVar3  
etc  
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

Answer (score 0):

`logger.debug()` outputs to the log.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger

Comment: this is not what I asked for =p I'm trying to further simplify the debug process. opening files every time you want to check your vars ain't my cup of tea.

Comment: `tail -f log/development.log`

Comment: `tail` is a unix utility to display the last part of a file, and the `-f` option keeps the output streaming when new text is added to the end of the file, so it's perfect for log files.